# Unhandled exception in using intrinsic

Tags: x86, sse, simd

I have an application created using VC++, and wanted to explore optimization opprtunity by vectorizing some operations.

To begin with, I am trying the following code :

```
__m128i p1;

p1.m128i_u32[0] = 1;
p1.m128i_u32[1] = 2;
p1.m128i_u32[2] = 3;
p1.m128i_u32[3] = 4;

__m128i p2;

p2.m128i_u32[0] = 1;
p2.m128i_u32[1] = 2;
p2.m128i_u32[2] = 3;
p2.m128i_u32[3] = 4;

__m128i res2= _mm_mul_epi32(p1,p2);
```

However, I am getting unhandled exception or illegal operation error when _mm_mul_epi32 is executed, I have no clue why it occurs.
Can someone please tell what is wrong?

Comment: Try the values used in the example on the MSDN page, rather than 1,2,3,4: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb514039.aspx

Comment: It's important for us that you accept an answer once you are done testing them, ok? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`_mm_mul_epi32` maps to the `PMULDQ` instruction, which is only available in SSE4 and AVX. You need to have a reasonably recent Intel CPU in order to have SSE4 or AVX, e.g. Nehalem, Sandy Bridge (Core i5, i7).

Note also that you might find it easier and more succinct to use intrinsics to initialise SIMD vectors, e.g.

```
__m128i p1 = _mm_set_epi32(1, 2, 3, 4);
__m128i p2 = _mm_set_epi32(1, 2, 3, 4);
__m128i res2 = _mm_mul_epi32(p1, p2);
```

Comment: eh my bad.. downloaded software http://www.cpuid.com/ and found out that my CPU has only instructions for "MMX, SSE (1,2,3,3S), EM64T"

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't you be using the member `m128i_i32` instead of `m128i_u32` ?

> This instruction multiplies two sets of 32-bit signed integers.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb514039.aspx).

If you really need `m128i_u32` then you must use `_mm_mul_epu32()` instead.

Comment: @fruit_trader Updated answer a few minutes ago. Did it worked for you?

Comment: In this case it makes no difference whether `m128i_i32` or `m128i_u32` is used, so this is probably not a helpful answer.

Comment: thanks for the reply. i missed to check my CPU - it does not have SSE4